Issue with Linking Secrets in Kubernetes Deployment YAML
Description

Blockquote

I'm trying to deploy an application using Kubernetes and Helm. My goal is to link environment variables from a Kubernetes Secret to my deployment. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to set up the environment variables correctly.
 spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.dockerRegistry }}{{ .Values.image.repository }}{{ .Values.image.imageName }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
          - name: "SECURITY_SSL_CA"
            value: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_CA | quote }}
          - name: "CA_TXT_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.CA_TXT_FILE | quote }}
          - name: "CA_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.CA_FILE | quote }}
          - name: "SECURITY_SSL_KEY"
            value: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_KEY | quote }}
          - name: "KEY_TXT_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.KEY_TXT_FILE | quote }}
          - name: "KEY_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.KEY_FILE | quote }}
          - name: "SN_USER"
            value: {{ .Values.env.SN_USER | quote }}
          - name: "SN_PASSWORD"
            value: {{ .Values.env.SN_PASSWORD | quote }}
          - name: "SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE | quote }}
          - name: "CRT_TXT_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.CRT_TXT_FILE | quote }}
          - name: "CRT_FILE"
            value: {{ .Values.env.CRT_FILE | quote }}

below is the method i have used for linking secret
---
secretName: certificate-secrets

env:
  SECURITY_SSL_CA: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlMQ=='
  CA_TXT_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlMg=='
  CA_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlMw=='
  SECURITY_SSL_KEY: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlNA=='
  KEY_TXT_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlNQ=='
  KEY_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlNg=='
  SN_USER: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlNw=='
  SN_PASSWORD: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlOA=='
  SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlOQ=='
  CRT_TXT_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlMTA=='
  CRT_FILE: 'YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2RlZHZhbHVlMTE=='
---
Secret Definition
Below is the method I have used for linking the secret:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "snp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  SECURITY_SSL_CA: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_CA | quote }}
  CA_TXT_FILE: {{ .Values.env.CA_TXT_FILE | quote }}
  CA_FILE: {{ .Values.env.CA_FILE | quote }}
  SECURITY_SSL_KEY: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_KEY | quote }}
  KEY_TXT_FILE: {{ .Values.env.KEY_TXT_FILE | quote }}
  KEY_FILE: {{ .Values.env.KEY_FILE | quote }}
  SN_USER: {{ .Values.env.SN_USER | quote }}
  SN_PASSWORD: {{ .Values.env.SN_PASSWORD | quote }}
  SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE: {{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE | quote }}
  CRT_TXT_FILE: {{ .Values.env.CRT_TXT_FILE | quote }}
  CRT_FILE: {{ .Values.env.CRT_FILE | quote }}
this is the deployment file 
---
My Helm Template
Here’s the Helm template I’m using for the container spec in my deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: my-image
          env:
            - name: SECURITY_SSL_CA
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: SECURITY_SSL_CA
            - name: CA_TXT_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: CA_TXT_FILE
            - name: CA_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: CA_FILE
            - name: SECURITY_SSL_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: SECURITY_SSL_KEY
            - name: KEY_TXT_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: KEY_TXT_FILE
            - name: KEY_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: KEY_FILE
            - name: SN_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: SN_USER
            - name: SN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: SN_PASSWORD
            - name: SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: SECURITY_SSL_CERTIFICATE
            - name: CRT_TXT_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: CRT_TXT_FILE
            - name: CRT_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
                  key: CRT_FILE

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: illegal base64 data at input byte 0



Are any of these values multi-line strings; is SECURITY_SSL_CA a complete X.509 certificate, for example?  Can you [edit] the question to reduce it to a single problematic variable and provide the corresponding configuration object and the actual error (and possibly also the helm template output)?

kindly check in answers -David Maze,

Helm's quote function is very simplistic: it takes the string it's given and it puts a double-quote character before and after it.  If your string has things like embedded newlines or itself contains double quotes, this might not produce valid YAML output.
One safe thing you can do is to use YAML block scalar syntax.  If you use a | character where the value would go, the following indented lines are combined together to form a multi-line string.  In Helm, you should use the indent function to consistently indent all of the lines of the string; since that also indents the first line, the line that includes the indent call should not itself be indented.
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: "SECURITY_SSL_CA"
            value: |
{{ .Values.env.SECURITY_SSL_CA | indent 14 }}

Another safe approach is to use toYaml to convert an arbitrary structure to YAML.  The structure will be correctly indented, but starting at the first column, so you will again need to indent it to the right place.
It looks like your Helm values structure has a key env containing an arbitrary map of environment variables, and you're just trying to copy them all out.  One approach here could be to use the range statement to iterate through .Values.env; for each key-value pair, produce the dictionary with name: and value: keys; and then serialize that with toYaml.
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.env }}
          - {{ dict "name" $k "value" $v | toYaml | indent 12 | trim }}
{{- end }}


I actually deployed this using everything same. Without secret.yaml file . I mentioned secrets in values.Yaml and simply mentioned their path in deployment. Yaml.  But that is off iurse not the right way. . Actually i am stuck now with secret.yaml file issue . When i am using athis method of referring secrets in helm charts then i am facing issue

I edited the question as asked if something is not clearing kindly let me know , I will share more details
